# Change MAC address immediately after system activation

Tags: networking, systemd, mac-address

I have few computers each with same ethernet MAC address. I want to change ethernet MAC address on each computer as soon as network card is detected so I do not have any conflicts in the network. My system is using nonstandard linux with systemd. Is it possible to configure MAC address using systemd and standard linux commands?

Comment: Configure a static IP of your own in `/etc/network/interface`!

Comment: @Thushi I was talking about mac address. IP address is taken from dhcp.

Comment: @Trismegistos, probably easiest to tie it to the distro's interface configuration scripts, and there might already be a system for doing that. Unless you really definitely want to do it manually, of course.

Comment: @Trismegistos: Ok, If that's the case please do mention it clearly in your question, one will think of IP address when you just mention ethernet address. Check adding `udev` rules.

Comment: @Thushi ethernet address is MAC it never been IP. IP protocol is hardware agnostic. Those are different OSI layers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the config line `HWADDR=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` in the machine's `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` config file, as such:

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
HWADDR=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
IPADDR=10.2.3.4
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=10.2.3.254
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=4.4.4.4
USERCTL=no
```

Comment: I meant MAC address not IP address. IP address is taken from DHCP and for that I need unique MAC address. Moreover there is not /etc/sysconfig on my computer. Linux distribution device runs is not standard one. I wanted to use systemd for that because it configures devices.

Comment: This is for RHEL.  Which Linux distro are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Parrot Home (Debian based distro) and after checking some sugestions I made a script to do it in every boot for eth0 and wlan0.

1. Login in root and install macchanger with `apt-get install macchanger -y`
2. Create a file in /etc/cron.daily/:
   `vim /etc/cron.daily/macchanger.sh`
3. Check the name of your network adapters with `ip a` (in the most of cases it's eth0 and wlan0, for Ethernet and Wi-Fi respectively) and put the follow code in the file:
   `#!/bin/bash sudo ifconfig eth0 down; sudo ifconfig wlan0 down; sudo macchanger -r eth0; sudo macchanger -r wlan0; sudo ifconfig eth0 up; sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`

   Exit vim by pressing ESC, write wq and pressing ENTER.
4. Make the file executable with `chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/macchanger.sh`
5. Create a crontab to execute your script with `crontab -e` and create a new final line with: `@reboot sh /etc/cron.daily/macchanger.sh`

These five steps created a automatic mac changer in linux in ever system startup!

Comment: A `sudo` command run under `cron` will fail unless you have configured it (`sudo`) to be passwordless. It’s better to use `sudo` to put the command into root’s crontab.

Comment: Thank you brother!

Comment: This only works after the network has already been initialized (hence why you start with ifconfig eth0 down) so I don't think this is the best solution.